# Разбор кучи строк

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть такая задача: Нужно разобрать среди тонны текста такую строку:

```
[00:21:53] Администратор Some_Nick[472] для Some_Nick[187]: Привет.
```

Нужно её сначала выявить из тонны другого текста (Всё это делается из текстового документа) и определить текст, который будет в конце ("Привет", к примеру, но текст может быть разный, хоть в 10 слов, хоть в одну букву).

P.S Пример того, что содержится в блокноте, из которого это нужно вытаскивать:

['[00:20:53] {FFFFFF}SA-MP {B9C9BF}0.3.7 {FFFFFF}Started\n', '\n', '[00:20:56] Connecting to 5.254.123.2:7777...\n', '\n', '[00:20:57] Connected. Joining the game...\n', '\n', '[00:20:59] Connected to {B9C9BF}Some Server\n', '\n', '[00:21:17] Аккаунт зарегистрирован\n', '\n', '[00:21:17] Чтобы открыть меню игрока введите {FFFF00}/menu (/mn)\n', '\n', '[00:21:19] • {FFC800}[Подсказка] {ffffff}Выберите своего начального персонажа и нажмите {CCBEDC}PLAY\n', '\n', '[00:21:32] LV | Куплю дом в г.Los-Santos. Бюджет: 666.666$. Отправитель: SOme_Nick (тел. 379014)\n', '\n', '[00:21:32]   Объявление проверил: Репортер Some_Nick (510)\n', '\n', '[00:21:32] Some_Nick[187]: {FFCD00}Привет!\n', '\n', '[00:21:32] Ожидайте, в ближайшее время Вам ответит администратор.\n', '\n', '[00:21:53] Администратор Some_Nick[472] для Some_Nick[187]: Привет.\n', '\n'

]

Как это сделать?

Comment: Регулярные выражения помогут.

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
import re

with codecs.open('alo', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        regexp = re.findall('[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]\s+Администратор\s+\w+_\w+\
                            [\d+\]\s+для\s+\w+_\w+\[\d+\]:(.*)', line)
        result = regexp[0]
        print(regexp,'\n\n', result)
```

Не забудь текстовый документ сохранить в кодировке UTF-8, иначе не считать кириллицу